# Recurrence relation for Huffman coding

Tags: algorithm, recursion, huffman-code

Suppose we recursively implement Huffman’s algorithm. Assume the input to the algorithm is a binary min-heap, where each node of the heap stores a character along with its associated probability. Provide a recurrence that describes the running time T(n) of the implementation.

Here I have to find a recurrence relation for the Huffman coding algorithm in the form

```
T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n).
```

What I have tried is explained below.

let our charset is [a,b,c,d,e] where they have their probabilities in decreasing order.

```
[a,b,c,d,e]
      |
[a,b,c,{d,e}]
      |
[a,b,{c,{d,e}}]
      |
[a,{b,{c,{d,e}}}]
      |
[{a,{b,{c,{d,e}}}}]
```

here we can see that subproblem is always one in each step so, the value of "a" = 1 and as we can do the combination of two characters in constant time so, "f(n) = 1". However, we are reducing the number of steps by 1 in each step, not we are dividing it by a factor of anything so I am not able to identify the value of "b".

I am not able to complete this equation. Can anyone help me?

Comment: That form of recurrence relation applies to divide and conquer algorithms. But there is no divide and conquer in the algorithm described in the question.

Comment: Any idea about which kind recurrence could be applied?

Comment: Based on your description of the algorithm's behavior, the recurrence relation would be `T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)`. However, the Huffman coding algorithm is not as simple as you have described. Before combining `d` and `e`, they must be popped from the min-heap. Then the combination `{d,e}` must be pushed onto the min-heap. Those aren't O(1) steps.